# How to find maxima\minima of given multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I need to find find the maxima/minima of the function

$f(x,y) = 2x^4 - 3x^2y +y^2$, I have figured out that $(0,0)$ is the only critical point of this function.

But $rt-s^2 = \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)\left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right) - {\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\right)}^2 = 0$ at $(0,0)$ and I  am stuck at this point.

I tried to  Change the function to $f(x,y) =  2\left({\left(x^2 -\dfrac{3y}{4}\right)}^2 - \dfrac{y^2}{16}\right)$ , to get some insight

But I am not sure How to proceed from here ?

Can anyone help me ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

As

$$
2 x^4 - 3 x^2 y + y^2 = (x^2 - y) (2 x^2 - y)
$$

consider the change of variable

$$
y = \mu x^2
$$